# Add text to generated quadrant area by x and y plot lines , highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a scatter chart  to demonstrate some load from the servers with two dimensions , x and y.

And I will define two plot lines to show if the point is overload, which is like the demo shows(just a quick demo , so I just copy the link):

```
"http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZprWa"
```

while, I also need to demonstrate that what is the  generated quadrant means with some labels simply like:

[image]

But I can't find any methods/options from the api to achieve this, is there any simple method to do this? Like find the position and put a label to it will absolute position?

Answer (score 2):

You can define plotLines per x and y axis and then catch load event. Inside that function, you should extract position of lines and use renderer to print labels. Last step is calculate osition to proper quarter (by comparing with plotLines and checking width of label - getBBox - function).

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        r = chart.renderer,
        each = Highcharts.each,
        left = chart.plotLeft,
        top = chart.plotTop,
        h = chart.plotHeight,
        w = chart.plotWidth,
        xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
        labels = ['top-left', 'top-right', 'bottom-left', 'bottom-right'],
        labelStyles = {
          'font-size': '12px',
          'color': 'red'
        },
        attr = {
          zIndex: 10
        },
        xPlotLine, yPlotLine,bbox, x, y;

      chart.label = [];

      xPlotLine = xAxis.toPixels(xAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value);
      yPlotLine = yAxis.toPixels(yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value);


      //render
      each(labels, function(label, i) {

        chart.label[i] = r.text(label, 0, 0)
          .attr(attr)
          .css(labelStyles)
          .add();

        bbox = chart.label[i].getBBox();
          console.log(w);
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
            x = ((xPlotLine + left) / 2) - (bbox.width / 2);
            y = ((yPlotLine + top) / 2) - (bbox.height / 2);
            break;
          case 1:
            x = left + xPlotLine + ((w - xPlotLine)/2) - (bbox.width / 2);
            y = ((yPlotLine + top) / 2) - (bbox.height / 2);
            break;
          case 2:
            x = ((xPlotLine + left) / 2) - (bbox.width / 2);
            y = top + yPlotLine + ((h - yPlotLine) / 2) - (bbox.height / 2);
            break;
          case 3:
            x = left + xPlotLine + ((w - xPlotLine)/2) - (bbox.width / 2);
            y = top + yPlotLine + ((h - yPlotLine) / 2) - (bbox.height / 2);
            break;
        }

        chart.label[i].attr({
            x: x,
          y: y
        });
      });

    }
  }
},
xAxis: {
  plotLines: [{
    id: 'ver',
    color: '#FF0000',
    width: 2,
    value: 2
  }]
},
yAxis: {
  plotLines: [{
    id: 'hor',
    color: '#FF0000',
    width: 2,
    value: 100
  }]
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x1zna57a/

Comment: Would you also update the code to codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZprWa, since I am blocked by the wall to access jsfiddle

Comment: A problem occurs when the plotlines does not show(larger than the max value of axis) see : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyPGax

Comment: You need to add condition which checks that coordinates of label are out of current range on axis. Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPJwZJ

Comment: A problem occurs that you could see a very small red label at left top since it was added to {x:0,y:0}, see you expample codepen.io/anon/pen/EPJwZJ . Is it possible that only add to the box when needed rather that add first than check? Or can we remove at "else statement", I tried  `chart.label[i].css({display:'none'})` , but it remove all.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Highcharts renderer api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) for more details. You can define a callback function like below after the chart is drawn and modify the charts.

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'Height (cm)'
      },
      threshold: 190,
      startOnTick: true,
      endOnTick: true,
      showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Weight (kg)'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      x: 100,
      y: 70,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
      scatter: {
        marker: {
          radius: 5,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled: true,
              lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
            }
          }
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
          pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Female',
      color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
      data: [
        [161.2, 51.6],
        [167.5, 59.0],
        [159.5, 49.2],
        [157.0, 63.0],
        [155.8, 53.6],
        [170.0, 59.0],
        [159.1, 47.6],
        [166.0, 69.8],
        [176.2, 66.8],
        [160.2, 75.2],
        [172.5, 55.2],
        [170.9, 54.2],
        [172.9, 62.5],
        [153.4, 42.0],
        [160.0, 50.0],
        [147.2, 49.8],
        [168.2, 49.2],
        [175.0, 73.2],
        [157.0, 47.8],
        [167.6, 68.8],
        [159.5, 50.6],
        [175.0, 82.5],
        [166.8, 57.2],
        [176.5, 87.8],
        [170.2, 72.8],
        [174.0, 54.5],
        [173.0, 59.8],
        [179.9, 67.3],
        [170.5, 67.8],
        [160.0, 47.0],
        [154.4, 46.2],
        [162.0, 55.0],
        [176.5, 83.0],
        [160.0, 54.4],
        [152.0, 45.8],
        [162.1, 53.6],
        [170.0, 73.2],
        [160.2, 52.1],
        [161.3, 67.9],
        [166.4, 56.6],
        [168.9, 62.3],
        [163.8, 58.5],
        [167.6, 54.5],
        [160.0, 50.2],
        [161.3, 60.3],
        [167.6, 58.3],
        [165.1, 56.2],
        [160.0, 50.2],
        [170.0, 72.9],
        [157.5, 59.8],
        [167.6, 61.0],
        [160.7, 69.1],
        [163.2, 55.9],
        [152.4, 46.5],
        [157.5, 54.3],
        [168.3, 54.8],
        [180.3, 60.7],
        [165.5, 60.0],
        [165.0, 62.0],
        [164.5, 60.3],
        [156.0, 52.7],
        [160.0, 74.3],
        [163.0, 62.0],
        [165.7, 73.1],
        [161.0, 80.0],
        [162.0, 54.7],
        [166.0, 53.2],
        [174.0, 75.7],
        [172.7, 61.1],
        [167.6, 55.7],
        [151.1, 48.7],
        [164.5, 52.3],
        [163.5, 50.0],
        [152.0, 59.3],
        [169.0, 62.5],
        [164.0, 55.7],
        [161.2, 54.8],
        [155.0, 45.9],
        [170.0, 70.6],
        [176.2, 67.2],
        [170.0, 69.4],
        [162.5, 58.2],
        [170.3, 64.8],
        [164.1, 71.6],
        [169.5, 52.8],
        [163.2, 59.8],
        [154.5, 49.0],
        [159.8, 50.0],
        [173.2, 69.2],
        [170.0, 55.9],
        [161.4, 63.4],
        [169.0, 58.2],
        [166.2, 58.6],
        [159.4, 45.7],
        [162.5, 52.2],
        [159.0, 48.6],
        [162.8, 57.8],
        [159.0, 55.6],
        [179.8, 66.8],
        [162.9, 59.4],
        [161.0, 53.6],
        [151.1, 73.2],
        [168.2, 53.4],
        [168.9, 69.0],
        [173.2, 58.4],
        [171.8, 56.2],
        [178.0, 70.6],
        [164.3, 59.8],
        [163.0, 72.0],
        [168.5, 65.2],
        [166.8, 56.6],
        [172.7, 105.2],
        [163.5, 51.8],
        [169.4, 63.4],
        [167.8, 59.0],
        [159.5, 47.6],
        [167.6, 63.0],
        [161.2, 55.2],
        [160.0, 45.0],
        [163.2, 54.0],
        [162.2, 50.2],
        [161.3, 60.2],
        [149.5, 44.8],
        [157.5, 58.8],
        [163.2, 56.4],
        [172.7, 62.0],
        [155.0, 49.2],
        [156.5, 67.2],
        [164.0, 53.8],
        [160.9, 54.4],
        [162.8, 58.0],
        [167.0, 59.8],
        [160.0, 54.8],
        [160.0, 43.2],
        [168.9, 60.5],
        [158.2, 46.4],
        [156.0, 64.4],
        [160.0, 48.8],
        [167.1, 62.2],
        [158.0, 55.5],
        [167.6, 57.8],
        [156.0, 54.6],
        [162.1, 59.2],
        [173.4, 52.7],
        [159.8, 53.2],
        [170.5, 64.5],
        [159.2, 51.8],
        [157.5, 56.0],
        [161.3, 63.6],
        [162.6, 63.2],
        [160.0, 59.5],
        [168.9, 56.8],
        [165.1, 64.1],
        [162.6, 50.0],
        [165.1, 72.3],
        [166.4, 55.0],
        [160.0, 55.9],
        [152.4, 60.4],
        [170.2, 69.1],
        [162.6, 84.5],
        [170.2, 55.9],
        [158.8, 55.5],
        [172.7, 69.5],
        [167.6, 76.4],
        [162.6, 61.4],
        [167.6, 65.9],
        [156.2, 58.6],
        [175.2, 66.8],
        [172.1, 56.6],
        [162.6, 58.6],
        [160.0, 55.9],
        [165.1, 59.1],
        [182.9, 81.8],
        [166.4, 70.7],
        [165.1, 56.8],
        [177.8, 60.0],
        [165.1, 58.2],
        [175.3, 72.7],
        [154.9, 54.1],
        [158.8, 49.1],
        [172.7, 75.9],
        [168.9, 55.0],
        [161.3, 57.3],
        [167.6, 55.0],
        [165.1, 65.5],
        [175.3, 65.5],
        [157.5, 48.6],
        [163.8, 58.6],
        [167.6, 63.6],
        [165.1, 55.2],
        [165.1, 62.7],
        [168.9, 56.6],
        [162.6, 53.9],
        [164.5, 63.2],
        [176.5, 73.6],
        [168.9, 62.0],
        [175.3, 63.6],
        [159.4, 53.2],
        [160.0, 53.4],
        [170.2, 55.0],
        [162.6, 70.5],
        [167.6, 54.5],
        [162.6, 54.5],
        [160.7, 55.9],
        [160.0, 59.0],
        [157.5, 63.6],
        [162.6, 54.5],
        [152.4, 47.3],
        [170.2, 67.7],
        [165.1, 80.9],
        [172.7, 70.5],
        [165.1, 60.9],
        [170.2, 63.6],
        [170.2, 54.5],
        [170.2, 59.1],
        [161.3, 70.5],
        [167.6, 52.7],
        [167.6, 62.7],
        [165.1, 86.3],
        [162.6, 66.4],
        [152.4, 67.3],
        [168.9, 63.0],
        [170.2, 73.6],
        [175.2, 62.3],
        [175.2, 57.7],
        [160.0, 55.4],
        [165.1, 104.1],
        [174.0, 55.5],
        [170.2, 77.3],
        [160.0, 80.5],
        [167.6, 64.5],
        [167.6, 72.3],
        [167.6, 61.4],
        [154.9, 58.2],
        [162.6, 81.8],
        [175.3, 63.6],
        [171.4, 53.4],
        [157.5, 54.5],
        [165.1, 53.6],
        [160.0, 60.0],
        [174.0, 73.6],
        [162.6, 61.4],
        [174.0, 55.5],
        [162.6, 63.6],
        [161.3, 60.9],
        [156.2, 60.0],
        [149.9, 46.8],
        [169.5, 57.3],
        [160.0, 64.1],
        [175.3, 63.6],
        [169.5, 67.3],
        [160.0, 75.5],
        [172.7, 68.2],
        [162.6, 61.4],
        [157.5, 76.8],
        [176.5, 71.8],
        [164.4, 55.5],
        [160.7, 48.6],
        [174.0, 66.4],
        [163.8, 67.3]
      ]

    }, {
      name: 'Male',
      color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
      data: [
        [174.0, 65.6],
        [175.3, 71.8],
        [193.5, 80.7],
        [186.5, 72.6],
        [187.2, 78.8],
        [181.5, 74.8],
        [184.0, 86.4],
        [184.5, 78.4],
        [175.0, 62.0],
        [184.0, 81.6],
        [180.0, 76.6],
        [177.8, 83.6],
        [192.0, 90.0],
        [176.0, 74.6],
        [174.0, 71.0],
        [184.0, 79.6],
        [192.7, 93.8],
        [171.5, 70.0],
        [173.0, 72.4],
        [176.0, 85.9],
        [176.0, 78.8],
        [180.5, 77.8],
        [172.7, 66.2],
        [176.0, 86.4],
        [173.5, 81.8],
        [178.0, 89.6],
        [180.3, 82.8],
        [180.3, 76.4],
        [164.5, 63.2],
        [173.0, 60.9],
        [183.5, 74.8],
        [175.5, 70.0],
        [188.0, 72.4],
        [189.2, 84.1],
        [172.8, 69.1],
        [170.0, 59.5],
        [182.0, 67.2],
        [170.0, 61.3],
        [177.8, 68.6],
        [184.2, 80.1],
        [186.7, 87.8],
        [171.4, 84.7],
        [172.7, 73.4],
        [175.3, 72.1],
        [180.3, 82.6],
        [182.9, 88.7],
        [188.0, 84.1],
        [177.2, 94.1],
        [172.1, 74.9],
        [167.0, 59.1],
        [169.5, 75.6],
        [174.0, 86.2],
        [172.7, 75.3],
        [182.2, 87.1],
        [164.1, 55.2],
        [163.0, 57.0],
        [171.5, 61.4],
        [184.2, 76.8],
        [174.0, 86.8],
        [174.0, 72.2],
        [177.0, 71.6],
        [186.0, 84.8],
        [167.0, 68.2],
        [171.8, 66.1],
        [182.0, 72.0],
        [167.0, 64.6],
        [177.8, 74.8],
        [164.5, 70.0],
        [192.0, 101.6],
        [175.5, 63.2],
        [171.2, 79.1],
        [181.6, 78.9],
        [167.4, 67.7],
        [181.1, 66.0],
        [177.0, 68.2],
        [174.5, 63.9],
        [177.5, 72.0],
        [170.5, 56.8],
        [182.4, 74.5],
        [197.1, 90.9],
        [180.1, 93.0],
        [175.5, 80.9],
        [180.6, 72.7],
        [184.4, 68.0],
        [175.5, 70.9],
        [180.6, 72.5],
        [177.0, 72.5],
        [177.1, 83.4],
        [181.6, 75.5],
        [176.5, 73.0],
        [175.0, 70.2],
        [174.0, 73.4],
        [165.1, 70.5],
        [177.0, 68.9],
        [192.0, 102.3],
        [176.5, 68.4],
        [169.4, 65.9],
        [182.1, 75.7],
        [179.8, 84.5],
        [175.3, 87.7],
        [184.9, 86.4],
        [177.3, 73.2],
        [167.4, 53.9],
        [178.1, 72.0],
        [168.9, 55.5],
        [157.2, 58.4],
        [180.3, 83.2],
        [170.2, 72.7],
        [177.8, 64.1],
        [172.7, 72.3],
        [165.1, 65.0],
        [186.7, 86.4],
        [165.1, 65.0],
        [174.0, 88.6],
        [175.3, 84.1],
        [185.4, 66.8],
        [177.8, 75.5],
        [180.3, 93.2],
        [180.3, 82.7],
        [177.8, 58.0],
        [177.8, 79.5],
        [177.8, 78.6],
        [177.8, 71.8],
        [177.8, 116.4],
        [163.8, 72.2],
        [188.0, 83.6],
        [198.1, 85.5],
        [175.3, 90.9],
        [166.4, 85.9],
        [190.5, 89.1],
        [166.4, 75.0],
        [177.8, 77.7],
        [179.7, 86.4],
        [172.7, 90.9],
        [190.5, 73.6],
        [185.4, 76.4],
        [168.9, 69.1],
        [167.6, 84.5],
        [175.3, 64.5],
        [170.2, 69.1],
        [190.5, 108.6],
        [177.8, 86.4],
        [190.5, 80.9],
        [177.8, 87.7],
        [184.2, 94.5],
        [176.5, 80.2],
        [177.8, 72.0],
        [180.3, 71.4],
        [171.4, 72.7],
        [172.7, 84.1],
        [172.7, 76.8],
        [177.8, 63.6],
        [177.8, 80.9],
        [182.9, 80.9],
        [170.2, 85.5],
        [167.6, 68.6],
        [175.3, 67.7],
        [165.1, 66.4],
        [185.4, 102.3],
        [181.6, 70.5],
        [172.7, 95.9],
        [190.5, 84.1],
        [179.1, 87.3],
        [175.3, 71.8],
        [170.2, 65.9],
        [193.0, 95.9],
        [171.4, 91.4],
        [177.8, 81.8],
        [177.8, 96.8],
        [167.6, 69.1],
        [167.6, 82.7],
        [180.3, 75.5],
        [182.9, 79.5],
        [176.5, 73.6],
        [186.7, 91.8],
        [188.0, 84.1],
        [188.0, 85.9],
        [177.8, 81.8],
        [174.0, 82.5],
        [177.8, 80.5],
        [171.4, 70.0],
        [185.4, 81.8],
        [185.4, 84.1],
        [188.0, 90.5],
        [188.0, 91.4],
        [182.9, 89.1],
        [176.5, 85.0],
        [175.3, 69.1],
        [175.3, 73.6],
        [188.0, 80.5],
        [188.0, 82.7],
        [175.3, 86.4],
        [170.5, 67.7],
        [179.1, 92.7],
        [177.8, 93.6],
        [175.3, 70.9],
        [182.9, 75.0],
        [170.8, 93.2],
        [188.0, 93.2],
        [180.3, 77.7],
        [177.8, 61.4],
        [185.4, 94.1],
        [168.9, 75.0],
        [185.4, 83.6],
        [180.3, 85.5],
        [174.0, 73.9],
        [167.6, 66.8],
        [182.9, 87.3],
        [160.0, 72.3],
        [180.3, 88.6],
        [167.6, 75.5],
        [186.7, 101.4],
        [175.3, 91.1],
        [175.3, 67.3],
        [175.9, 77.7],
        [175.3, 81.8],
        [179.1, 75.5],
        [181.6, 84.5],
        [177.8, 76.6],
        [182.9, 85.0],
        [177.8, 102.5],
        [184.2, 77.3],
        [179.1, 71.8],
        [176.5, 87.9],
        [188.0, 94.3],
        [174.0, 70.9],
        [167.6, 64.5],
        [170.2, 77.3],
        [167.6, 72.3],
        [188.0, 87.3],
        [174.0, 80.0],
        [176.5, 82.3],
        [180.3, 73.6],
        [167.6, 74.1],
        [188.0, 85.9],
        [180.3, 73.2],
        [167.6, 76.3],
        [183.0, 65.9],
        [183.0, 90.9],
        [179.1, 89.1],
        [170.2, 62.3],
        [177.8, 82.7],
        [179.1, 79.1],
        [190.5, 98.2],
        [177.8, 84.1],
        [180.3, 83.2],
        [180.3, 83.2]
      ]
    }]
  }, function (chart) {

var points= chart.series[0].data;
var highX = { plotX: -12};
debugger;
for(var i=0;i< points.length;i++){
    if((points[i].plotX  - highX.plotX) > 0)
    highX = points[i];
}
debugger;
        highX,
            text = chart.renderer.text(
                'Max',
                highX.plotX,// + chart.plotLeft + 10,
                highX.plotY// + chart.plotTop - 10
            ).attr({
                zIndex: 5
            }).add(),
            box = text.getBBox();

        chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 5, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
            .attr({
                fill: '#FFFFEF',
                stroke: 'gray',
                'stroke-width': 1,
                zIndex: 4
            })
            .add();
    });
});
```

updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPovyM#0)

on the callback function apply your logic for threshold and add the labels, hope this helps

Comment: Would you please also update to the codepen? since I was blocked by the wall that I can't get access to fiddle

Comment: `this.chart.renderer.label('High X & Y', 570, 250)` ; but you are hard coded the label, but I need it to show at appropriate position according to the plotlines.